# Loose ID on soundscape recordings from Borneo

Tags: insect, spectrogram-annotation, identification, species-identification, call-identification

I'm doing some outreach and wanted to show some examples of what species can be ID'd from audio recordings.

I've ID'd the Gibbon and a Bearded Pig (blue and red boxes ,respectively) + am getting some help on the birds. Do you know what the regular broadband signals (particularly those in boxes)could be - I'm thinking insect, but any clues would be great!

[Link to download the Audio here](https://imperialcollegelondon.box.com/s/obi0fq6kf7e5oidbj1sig5ayr5gq5g1t)

---

EDIT:

Terrestrial recordings from Malaysian Borneo (Sabah)

AudioMoths ~1m off the ground

March 2019, 6:20am (dawn chorus)

---

Thanks

[image]

unannotated:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the recordings? What time of day were the recordings? Time of year? More specific location of the hydrophone? I won't be able to ID, but additional details might help others. Thanks! Sounds awesome!

Comment: @angie_zorka great idea actually - cheers

Comment: It might be helpful to be more specific with the main question so people know what you're looking for. Can you include a link to audio files for people to listen to?

Comment: @ASimonis I've got a link but I'll make it a bit clearer! thanks

Comment: The red one is scary in the sound recording!!!

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Borneo, but not going to let that stop me...

You have sporadic triplets/quads, with a clear peak around 17 kHz, and varying amplitude - I would say bat calls for these.

I would agree that the regularly spaced calls at 15 kHz (your green box) are likely to be invertebrates.

A lot of bird song/call at 1-9 kHz, as you say.

I think your yellow box, peaking at 7.5 kHz and with a variable shape is probably a high frequency bird.

Probably no use at all that - but great to listen to!